# External projects can be seen in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm seeing this in Solution Explorer:

[image]

How do I remove all these

Comment: And you can not just delete them by pressing the ```Delete``` key? or Right click one of them and select remove?

Comment: @Tomek Even if he did, they would be regenerated right after adding a class to the Unity project.

Comment: `How do I remove all these` -> You don't .. just ignore them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of Unity, you can control this behavior in `Edit/Preferences/External Tools`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I once did that to improve autocomplete and I forgot to do it again.